# Codeigniter 3 session dont get loaded right - some times?

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

So i work on quite a large appliaction. And we have been getting reports that our login don't work as expected. I've been looking around for some time now - and every question that is similar to mine have been left unanswered.

This is my session config.

```
$some_other_config["sess_cookie_name"]= "the_one_i_want_session"; 
$some_other_config["sess_expiration"]= 2678400;
$some_other_config["sess_encrypt_cookie"]= false; 
$some_other_config["sess_use_database"]= true; 
$some_other_config["sess_table_name"]= "db_session"; 
$some_other_config["sess_match_ip"]= false; 
$some_other_config["sess_match_useragent"]= false; 
$some_other_config["sess_time_to_update"]= 7200;
```

Also, we have one more session

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'really_unimportant_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 2678400;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'a_non_exisiting_legacy_table';
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/path/to/the/sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
```

Now here is the funny part "the_one_i_want_session" is the one keeping track of the user being logged in or not, right?

Well, if I connect to a vpn (i think it might be the IP change) and connect to whatever country, I won't be able to log in. We can log in in two ways: With a ajax post-request, or a regular form post.

They are basically the same, when you log in to the ajax, the login gives the correct login successful state, we write the session, it get stored in the database, and we give the user a successful message, and a choice to where to go next. When we do another request, the session is not updated.

With the regular form-post, the excact same happens but we do a redirect with the codeigniter framework. Again the session hits the db, but after the redirect the session is not connected to the browser.

Kicker: if i disable my vpn, it everything works, like a charm. I used Private Internet Access for this test.

I don't really know where to go next. The only thing i have seen is that in CI3 the session is supposed to work together with the $_SESSION superglobal, but my $_SESSION is always NULL. Could there be a problem with two sessions defined?

Edit: 
One more thing i forgot to mention is. This only happens in production. We basically have a mirror of the site, with almost the same config (session configs are the same), and login works on the mirrored site.

Edit2:
It seems that even the setcookie-function does what it is supposed to do, and returns true. Im confused.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. To make it even stranger it is only evident on one type of phone using chrome. The problem doesn't persist on a mirror I created for testing on 000webhost. Never found a solution either her or on the CI forums probably due to improbability of people being able to replicate the issue. I can say that it seemed that ajax was causing the problem (whenever there was an ajax request the session reset). I dug through the session code with a fine toothed comb and nothing. I finally gave up.